model. fit() doesn't work when I use class_weight with image segmentation
When creating the dictionary with the weight values, model.fit() does not train, it shows the following error
I used the following code
import pathlib
import tensorflow as tf
import imageio
import numpy as np
import keras
import glob
import random
import os
os.environ["SM_FRAMEWORK"] = "tf.keras"
import segmentation_models as sm
#import cv2
from tqdm import tqdm
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image
from model_segmentation import simple_unet_model
from keras.metrics import MeanIoU
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder


img = img[...,np.newaxis]
print(img.shape)
print(msk.shape)
#msk = msk[...,np.newaxis]
kernel_initializer =  'he_uniform' #Try others if you want

steps_per_epoch = len(train_img_list)//batch_size
#val_steps_per_epoch = len(val_img_list)//batch_size

model = simple_unet_model(IMG_HEIGHT=128, IMG_WIDTH=128, IMG_CHANNELS=1, num_classes=4)

total_loss = 'binary_crossentropy'
#metrics = ['accuracy', sm.metrics.IOUScore(threshold=0.5)]
metrics = ['accuracy']
optim = 'adam'

model.compile(optimizer = optim, loss=total_loss, metrics= metrics)
print(model.summary())

print(model.input_shape)
print(model.output_shape)

msk = msk.astype(np.uint8)
print(msk.shape)
msk_argmax=np.argmax(msk, axis=3)
masks_reshaped = msk_argmax.reshape(-1,1)
print(masks_reshaped.shape)
masks_reshaped_encoded = masks_reshaped.reshape(-1)
print(masks_reshaped_encoded.shape)

labelencoder = LabelEncoder()
masks_reshaped_encoded = labelencoder.fit_transform(masks_reshaped)
print(masks_reshaped_encoded.shape)

np.unique(masks_reshaped_encoded)

class_weights_manual= {0:1, 1:2, 2:4, 3:8}

history=model.fit(img, msk, epochs=50, verbose=1, validation_split=0.2, shuffle=False,
                  class_weight=class_weights_manual)


  File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\utils\traceback_utils.py:122 in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None

  File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\trainers\data_adapters\data_adapter_utils.py:126 in class_weight_to_sample_weights
    sample_weight[i] = class_weight.get(int(y[i]), 1.0)

TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

Does the training data have to have a specific format?
or what do I need to change in the code?
I attach screenshots, thanks for your help

Is there a chance that masks_reshaped_encoded is supposed to be passed to fit() method instead of msk?

it couldn't do, because variables have different dimensions  print(img.shape) (1000, 128, 128, 1) print(msk.shape) (1000, 128, 128, 4) print(masks_reshaped_encoded.shape) (16384000,) np.unique(masks_reshaped_encoded) Out[11]: array([0, 1, 2, 3], dtype=int64)

Ok, but I don't quite get it. If you pass msk (with shape (1000, 128, 128, 4)) as y to fit() what does class_weights_manual mean in this case? If your y has shape 128, 128, 4 how it is supposed to be connencted with classes 0, 1, 2, 3 from class_weights_manual?

@mz2300 class_weights_manual is the dictionary (class: weight value)  y= (1000, 128, 128, 4)  1000 is the number of samples, 128, 128 is the size and 4 is the number of class 0,1,2,3   everything is included in this line of code  history=model.fit(img, msk, epochs=50, verbose=1, validation_split=0.2, shuffle=False,class_weight=class_weights_manual)

Based on keras implementation of this argument :
def class_weight_to_sample_weights(y, class_weight):
    sample_weight = np.ones(shape=(y.shape[0],), dtype=backend.floatx())
    if len(y.shape) > 1:
        if y.shape[-1] != 1:
            y = np.argmax(y, axis=-1)
        else:
            y = np.squeeze(y, axis=-1)
    y = np.round(y).astype("int32")
    for i in range(y.shape[0]):
        sample_weight[i] = class_weight.get(int(y[i]), 1.0)
    return sample_weight

I think it is useful ONLY in case of classical classification problems. It expects y is going to be a list of classes (ohe-hot encoded or not) but not an image array (even it contains these classes).

Do you have any idea how I can balance the weights of a set of images?  thanks for your help
